# InvalidAuxServiceException in MapReduce Job

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I am getting the following exception while running a map-reduce job on recently created open source hadoop cluster. I am running the latest hadoop version 3.3.0.

```
2020-09-03 00:58:30,068 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1599094453872_0001_m_000000_2, Status : FAILED
Container launch failed for container_1599094453872_0001_01_000004 : org.apache.hadoop.yarn.exceptions.InvalidAuxServiceException: The auxService:mapreduce_shuffle does not exist
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:83)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:437)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateExceptionImpl(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:171)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.instantiateException(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:182)
        at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.api.records.impl.pb.SerializedExceptionPBImpl.deSerialize(SerializedExceptionPBImpl.java:106)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$Container.launch(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:163)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.v2.app.launcher.ContainerLauncherImpl$EventProcessor.run(ContainerLauncherImpl.java:394)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1160)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:820)
```

As per some of the online suggestions, I have added the following two properties in yarn-site.xml and restarted both yarn and dfs. However, it is still throwing the same exception as above. Sometimes the job succeeds with the exception.

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
```

Comment: Did you follow the official Hadoop suggestion? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/PluggableShuffleAndPluggableSort.html

Comment: As per the official hadoop suggestion, I tried putting the properties. I restarted dfs and resourcemanager. I am still getting the same exception. Now, the map-reduce job is also not succeeding. Below are the properties in my yarn-site.xml.

Comment: <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
        <value>mapreduce_shuffle,AuxServiceFromHDFS</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce_shuffle.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
    </property>
    <property>
        <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.AuxServiceFromHDFS.class</name>
        <value>org.apache.auxtest.AuxServiceFromHDFS2</value>
    </property>

Comment: I have tried almost all of the different solutions from the web. But it is still not working. I can not figure out what is it that I am doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I am really stuck with this issue. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.